# Is there an alternative to using multiple AND operators?

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services

My overall goal is to return all items that are in-stock, that also follow the guidelines set by the AND operators. As you can see, there are quite a few columns, and this query won't even run. Can I replace all of the AND's with something more efficient that works?

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
itemwhse.item,
itemwhse.whse,
itemwhse.qty_on_hand

FROM itemwhse, MQG_ProdSpec
WHERE itemwhse.qty_on_hand >= 1

AND MQG_ProdSpec.Ind_L < 1
AND MQG_ProdSpec.Ind_W < 1
AND MQG_ProdSpec.Ind_H < 1
AND MQG_ProdSpec.Ind_NW < 1
AND MQG_ProdSpec.Ind_GW < 1 

AND MQG_ProdSpec.InPk_H < 1
AND MQG_ProdSpec.InPk_L < 1
AND MQG_ProdSpec.InPk_W < 1
AND MQG_ProdSpec.InPk_NW < 1
AND MQG_ProdSpec.InPk_GW < 1

AND MQG_ProdSpec.Master_H < 1
AND MQG_ProdSpec.Master_L < 1
AND MQG_ProdSpec.Master_W < 1
AND MQG_ProdSpec.Master_NW < 1
AND MQG_ProdSpec.Master_GW < 1
```

Comment: why you mean doesnt run? any error message?

Comment: What is "less than a string constant" supposed to be doing?  The code isn't very clear.  What values can each column take on?  And, you should learn proper explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: I'm naive and new to this, so bear with me: It "runs", but shows no data, only column headers.

Comment: I apologize for the code. When it says, " MQG_ProdSpec.column < 1", it's supposed to return all items that have fewer than 1 (1 and greater being a measurement/dimension)

Comment: Are the columns `MQG_ProdSpec.Ind_L` integer? or decimal? Can they be negative or zero?

Comment: They are decimal. They can be zero, but not negative.

Comment: You are cross joining the two tables, i.e. you combine every `itemwhse` record with every `MQG_ProdSpec`. If you are still not getting any result row, this means that either there is no record in `itemwhse` with `qty_on_hand >= 1` or no record in `MQG_ProdSpec` matching all conditions.

Comment: As @Gordon Linoff wrote, you are comparing a decimal and a string: `'1'` is not the same as `1` or `1.0`. Remove quotes from '1'.

Comment: For some reason, the query won't run when I try to execute the whole thing. However, it will run if I execute everything except the last portion of AND operators at the bottom.. Is there a limit to how many AND's I can use?

Answer (score -1):

I think the keyword OR is required inplace of AND, otherwise all conditions need to be true.

Comment: Eh, I dont think so. I need the items to match all the conditions, not one over another.